# Android ExpandableListView not updating the changes to adapter

Tags: android

I am using some Switches in an ExpandableListView. But after I change the switch values and scroll the ExpandableListView, the switches are automatically set to the defaults.
These are my codes

```
    @Override
        public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        //attach a listener to check for changes in state
        viewHolder.switchChild.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {

         if(isChecked)
         {
                _MyOfferFilterData.get(childPosition).setValue("true");

        }
        else
        {
            _MyOfferFilterData.get(childPosition).setValue("false"); 

        }   
       }      


   }
```

Comment: have you notify ExpandableListView ? using notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: Where you update your row layout in *getChildView()* ?

Comment: yes,I have notify adapter using notifyDataSetChanged(). but it doesn't work

Comment: I am passing an arraylist from Activity class to adapter class. I want to update that arraylist when do changes in the adapter class

Comment: Please be much clearer. What kind of arraylist? For what? What kind of changes are you doing in the adapter class? You should know that the item views of a listview get recycled. I don't see you accounting for that. You are not using MyOfferFilterData in getChildView to set the state of switchChild.

Answer (score 0):

Are you populating the ArrayList from DB everytime you load the ExpandableListView? If yes, then while setting the flag in ArrayList, you also have to set the flag in the DB. Otherwise, ArrayList will get refreshed with what is there in DB when ExpandableListView refreshes.